# Use data from JSON file with Leaflet GeoJSON marker

Tags: leaflet, geojson, mapping, json, markers

I have a JSON file that I am fetching from and I would like to use the 'LAT' and 'LON' attribute to place markers. The problem is I am unable to see any markers appear. I think it's because the file is not formatted as a GeoJSON file. I've tried to implement it in my getBuildings function. The format of the URL JSON file is

```js
[{
"BLDGCODE": "B800000001",
"BLDG": "0001",
"NAME": "University Auditorium",
"ABBREV": "AUD",
"OFFICIAL_ROOM_NAME": "Friends of Music Room",
"LAT": 29.64898,
"LON": -82.34292
}, ...
]
```

````js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Leaflet from 'leaflet'; 
import 'leaflet-search';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map', 
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})

export class MapComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor() {}

  serviceData="";
  buildingData="";
  private map!: Leaflet.Map;
  private centroid: Leaflet.LatLngExpression = [29.64833, -82.34944];
  geojson: Leaflet.GeoJSON<any> | null = null;
  _json: any;
  buildingjson: any;

  

  private initMap(): void {
    
    // Making a map and tiles
    this.map = Leaflet.map('map').setView(this.centroid, 16);
    const attribution = '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>';

    const tileUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    const OSM = Leaflet.tileLayer(tileUrl, {attribution});
    this.map.addLayer(OSM);
    // tiles.addTo(this.map);
    
    // Making a marker with an icon
    var myIcon = Leaflet.icon({
      iconUrl: 'marker-icon.png',
      iconSize: [25, 32],
      iconAnchor: [25, 32],
    });
    const marker = Leaflet.marker([0,0], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(this.map);
    marker.setLatLng(this.centroid);
  }

  

  getBuildings($event: any) {
    this.buildingData = $event
    const url = 'http://localhost:4200/api/search/offline/' + this.buildingData;
    console.log(this.buildingData);
    console.log(url);

    var myIcon = Leaflet.icon({
      iconUrl: 'marker-icon.png',
      iconSize: [25, 32],
      iconAnchor: [25, 32],
    });


    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json);
      if (this._json) {
        this._json.clearLayers();
        this._json.addData(json);
      }
      else {
        this._json = Leaflet.geoJSON(json, {

        })
        .addTo(this.map);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error!')
      console.error(error)
    });
  }
    
  
  getParkingLots($event: any) {
    this.serviceData = $event
    const url = 'http://localhost:4200/api/filter/decal/' + this.serviceData;
    console.log(url)
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json);
      if (this.geojson) {
        this.geojson.clearLayers();
        this.geojson.addData(json);
        this.map.fitBounds(this.geojson.getBounds());
      }
      else {
        this.geojson = Leaflet.geoJSON(json, {
          style: function(feature) {
            switch (feature?.properties.Lot_Class)
            {
              case 'Brown': return {color: 'brown', fillColor: 'brown', fillOpacity: 0.2};
              case 'Brown 3': return {color: 'brown', fillColor: 'brown', fillOpacity: 0.2};
              case 'Orange': return {color: 'orange', fillColor: 'orange', fillOpacity: 0.2};
              case 'Red': return {color: 'red', fillColor: 'red', fillOpacity: 0.2}
              case 'Red One': return {color: 'red', fillColor: 'red', fillOpacity: 0.2}
              case 'Blue': return {color: 'blue', fillColor: 'blue', fillOpacity: 0.2}
              case 'Green': return {color: 'green', fillColor: 'green', fillOpacity: 0.2}
              case 'Student Green': return {color: 'green', fillColor: 'green', fillOpacity: 0.2}
            }
            return {
              color: 'black',
              fillColor: 'black',
              fillOpacity: 0.2
            };
          },
          onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
            if (feature.properties.Lot_Name == null) {
              layer.bindPopup('Lot: I have no name :(')
            }
            else {
              layer.bindPopup('Lot: ' + feature.properties.Lot_Name);
            }  
            // layer.on('mouseover', function (e) {
            //   layer.openPopup();
            // })
            // layer.on('mouseout', function (e) {
            //   layer.closePopup();
            // })
          }
        })
        .addTo(this.map);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error!')
      console.error(error)
    });
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {  
    this.initMap();
  }
  
}
 
    // this.dataService.share.subscribe(x => this.serviceData = x);
  
    // const url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/filter/decal/' + this.serviceData; 

    // async function load_shapefile() {
    //   const response = await fetch(url)
    //   const shape_obj = await response.json();
    //   console.log(shape_obj);
    //   return shape_obj;
    // }

    // load_shapefile().then(Leaflet.geoJSON).then(this.map.addLayer.bind(this.map));
   
    // fetch(url, {
    //   method: 'GET'
    // })
    // .then(response => response.json())
    // .then(json => {
    //   console.log(json)
    //   var geojson = Leaflet.geoJSON(json, {
    //     style: function (feature) {
    //       return {
    //         fillOpacity: 0
    //       };
    //     }
    //   }).addTo(this.map)
    // })
    // .catch(error => console.log(error.message));```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data is not in GeoJSON format, you cannot use it as an input to Leaflet GeoJSON layer. You have to iterate it, create markers yourselves and than  add to layer which can be Leaflet group layer.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET'
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {
  if (this._json) {
    this._json.clearLayers();
  }
  else {
    this._json = Leaflet.layerGroup().addTo(this.map);
  }
  json.forEach(function(item) {
    Leaflet.marker([item.LAT, item.LON], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(this._json);
  });
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('error!')
  console.error(error)
});
```